# CSS Animation (Appear from the side by clicking)

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make something apppear from the right side in a div when I'm click on it.
It's a Div (dish) that have 2 Div in it (infoDish) and (validation).
infoDish have a width of 100%, validation have a width of 20% but is hidden unless I click on Dish.

I can make validation appear and disappear but the thing is it's instantaneus and I want to create an animation that take 1 or 2 seconds to make it appear from the right side (like you open the window from the right to the left).

```css
.plat {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 70px;
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.plat:hover .divValid {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  background-color: #99E2D0;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

.partRouge {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTitlePlat {
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.divTitlePlat h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.divInfoPlat {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.divDescPlat {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.divPricePlat {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=menuresto.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="plat">
                            <div class="partRouge">
                                <div class="divTitlePlat">
                                    <h3>Tartare de poulpe acidulé</h3>
                                </div>

                                <div class="divInfoPlat">
                                    <div class="divDescPlat">
                                        <span>Aux zests d'orange</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divPricePlat">
                                        <span class="price">25€</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divValid">
                                <!--<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you really want to do...
But if you want to add a little delay, not to change instantly you can add the CSS property transition in the class with the hover. You can even precise for each property you want a delay and the delay. To do this, you have to write:

```
transition: 1s;
```

To have more informations about this property, you can read:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

With your code, it's not perfect but if it's what you were searching for, the changement on the hover is now not instantly, but with a delay of 1 second.

```css
.plat {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 70px;
  width: 95%;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.plat:hover .divValid {
  border: 1px solid purple;
  background-color: #99E2D0;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  transition: 1s;
}

.partRouge {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.divTitlePlat {
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.divTitlePlat h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.divInfoPlat {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.divDescPlat {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.divPricePlat {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=menuresto.css.map */
```

```html
<div class="plat">
   <div class="partRouge">
      <div class="divTitlePlat">
         <h3>Tartare de poulpe acidulé</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="divInfoPlat">
         <div class="divDescPlat">
            <span>Aux zests d'orange</span>
         </div>
         <div class="divPricePlat">
            <span class="price">25€</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="divValid">
      <!--<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>-->
   </div>
</div>
```